# Change user account type from administrator to standard

Tags: fedora, settings, accounts, user-interface

In Fedora 21, I changed the user account type from standard to an administrator. Now, I want to change it back via UI but the option that I used before (`Settings → Users → Account type`) doesn't work anymore. How can I change the user account type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First determine the groups the user belongs to from a terminal.

```
groups USER
```

In the following command type only the groups that you wan't to keep being in, administrator accounts are usually part of the `wheel` or `sudo` group, so don't type that one in.

```
usermod -G GROUP1,GROUP2 USER
```

The man page for usermod(8) has more information.

```
man 8 usermod
```